# Understanding actor and making it thread safe

Tags: swift, concurrency, actor, combine

I have an actor that is processing values and is then publishing the values with a Combine Publisher.

I have problems understanding actors, I thought when using actors in an async context, it would automatically be serialised. However, the numbers get processed in different orders and not in the expected order (see class tests for comparison).

I understand that if I would wrap Task around the for loop that then this would be returned serialised, but my understanding is, that I could call a function of an actor and this would then be automatically serialised.

How can I make my actor thread safe so it publishes the values in the expected order even if it is called from a different thread?

```
import XCTest
import Combine
import CryptoKit

actor AddNumbersActor {
    private let _numberPublisher: PassthroughSubject<(Int,String), Never> = .init()
    nonisolated lazy var numberPublisher = _numberPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
    func process(_ number: Int) {
            let string = SHA512.hash(data: Data(String(number).utf8))
                .description
            _numberPublisher.send((number, string))
    }
}

class AddNumbersClass {
    private let _numberPublisher: PassthroughSubject<(Int,String), Never> = .init()
    lazy var numberPublisher = _numberPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
    func process(_ number: Int) {
            let string = SHA512.hash(data: Data(String(number).utf8))
                .description
            _numberPublisher.send((number, string))
    }
}


final class TestActorWithPublisher: XCTestCase {
    var subscription: AnyCancellable?
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        subscription = nil
    }

    func testActor() throws {
        let addNumbers = AddNumbersActor()
        var numbersResults = [(int: Int, string: String)]()
        let expectation = expectation(description: "numberOfExpectedResults")
        let numberCount = 1000
        subscription = addNumbers.numberPublisher
            .sink { results in
                print(results)
                numbersResults.append(results)
                if numberCount == numbersResults.count {
                    expectation.fulfill()
                }
            }
        
        
        for number in 1...numberCount {
            Task {
                await addNumbers.process(number)
            }
        }
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)
        print(numbersResults.count)
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults[10].0, 11)
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults[100].0, 101)
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults[500].0, 501)
    }
    
    func testClass() throws {
        let addNumbers = AddNumbersClass()
        var numbersResults = [(int: Int, string: String)]()
        let expectation = expectation(description: "numberOfExpectedResults")
        let numberCount = 1000
        subscription = addNumbers.numberPublisher
            .sink { results in
                print(results)
                numbersResults.append(results)
                if numberCount == numbersResults.count {
                    expectation.fulfill()
                }
            }
        for number in 1...numberCount {
            addNumbers.process(number)
        }
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)
        print(numbersResults.count)
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults[10].0, 11)
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults[100].0, 101)
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults[500].0, 501)
    }
}

``
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `actor` does indeed serialize access.

The issue you're running into is that the tests aren't testing whether calls to `process()` are serialized, they are testing the execution order of the calls. And the execution order of the `Task` calls is not guaranteed.

Try changing your `AddNumbers` objects so that instead of the output order reflecting the order in which the calls were made, they will succeed if calls are serialized but will fail if concurrent calls are made. You can do this by keeping a `count` variable, incrementing it, sleeping a bit, then publishing the count. Concurrent calls will fail, since `count` will be incremented multiple times before its returned.

If you make that change, the test using an Actor will pass. The test using a class will fail if it calls `process()` concurrently:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
    addNumbers.process()
}
```

It will also help to understand that `Task`'s scheduling depends on a bunch of stuff. GCD will spin up tons of threads, whereas Swift concurrency will only use 1 worker thread per available core (I think!). So in some execution environments, just wrapping your work in `Task { }` might be enough to serialize it for you. I've been finding that iOS simulators act as if they have a single core, so task execution ends up being serialized. Also, otherwise unsafe code will work if you ensure the task runs on the main actor, since it guarantees serial execution:

```
Task { @MainActor in
    // ...
}
```

Here are modified tests showing all this:

```
class TestActorWithPublisher: XCTestCase {
    actor AddNumbersActor {
        private let _numberPublisher: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never> = .init()
        nonisolated lazy var numberPublisher = _numberPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        var count = 0
        
        func process() {
            // Increment the count here
            count += 1
            
            // Wait a bit...
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: TimeInterval.random(in: 0...0.010))
            
            // Send it back. If other calls to process() were made concurrently, count may have been incremented again before being sent:
            _numberPublisher.send(count)
        }
    }

    class AddNumbersClass {
        private let _numberPublisher: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never> = .init()
        lazy var numberPublisher = _numberPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        var count = 0
        
        func process() {
            count += 1
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: TimeInterval.random(in: 0...0.010))
            _numberPublisher.send(count)
        }
    }

    
    var subscription: AnyCancellable?
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        subscription = nil
    }
    
    func testActor() throws {
        let addNumbers = AddNumbersActor()
        var numbersResults = [Int]()
        let expectation = expectation(description: "numberOfExpectedResults")
        let numberCount = 1000
        subscription = addNumbers.numberPublisher
            .sink { results in
                numbersResults.append(results)
                if numberCount == numbersResults.count {
                    expectation.fulfill()
                }
            }
        
        for _ in 1...numberCount {
                Task.detached(priority: .high) {
                    await addNumbers.process()
                }
        }
        
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults, Array(1...numberCount))
    }
    
    func testClass() throws {
        let addNumbers = AddNumbersClass()
        var numbersResults = [Int]()
        let expectation = expectation(description: "numberOfExpectedResults")
        let numberCount = 1000
        subscription = addNumbers.numberPublisher
            .sink { results in
                numbersResults.append(results)
                if numberCount == numbersResults.count {
                    expectation.fulfill()
                }
            }
        
        for _ in 1...numberCount {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
                addNumbers.process()
            }
        }
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(numbersResults, Array(1...numberCount))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! This was not the solution I was looking for.
This however describes the cause of my problem pretty good:
"The issue you're running into is that the tests aren't testing whether calls to process() are serialized, they are testing the execution order of the calls. And the execution order of the Task calls is not guaranteed." I guess this is not possible with actor. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't really answer your question. But I don't believe Swift concurrency provides the clear answer you're hoping for.

You might find these forum threads and this WWDC talk helpful:
https://forums.swift.org/t/task-is-order-of-task-execution-deterministic/51553/2
https://forums.swift.org/t/how-do-you-use-asyncstream-to-make-task-execution-deterministic/57968
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022-110351

In your test example, probably the most straightforward thing to do is to wrap your `for` loop in a single task (like you suggested in your question).